How to resolve bash: docker: command not found, inside docker container?
I am using docker on windows. And everything works fine. I can create images and docker containers.
Version of docker is:
docker -v:Docker version 26.1.1, build 4cf5afa

And I added  in the environments variables of windows this paths:
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin

But if I try to connect from a docker container to a other nework inside a docker container:
root@032194c3eca0:/# docker exec dwl_backend_rachid-web-1 bash -c "ping 172.18.0.3"

Then the following error pops up:
bash: docker: command not found

Question: how to resolve this error?

Wait, ignore my earlier command, I misread: most docker images won't have the docker command installed in them, why should they? They run on docker and are not meant to interact with other containers (and usually can't, unless you explicitly give them access to the socket).

@JoachimSauer ? What is then the command to ping a other docker container inside a docker container? I have read that you can do it with the command I posted

Breaking the isolation features of Docker would be a bad idea if it was possible. You are not supposed to be able to talk to the host which is running the Docker image, by design.

A Docker container is a wrapper around a single process, and processes rarely directly handle ICMP messages.  Why is sending an ICMP ECHO packet using ping(1) important?

Is there a specific reason not to use Docker exec from the windows cmd? Otherwise, just run ping on its own from that container

You have to install the docker CLI inside your image.
Here is my solution to the same problem (that can customize on your needs):
FROM <YOUR_DEBIAN_BASED_IMAGE>

RUN apt update -y
RUN apt install -y curl
RUN curl https://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz | tar xvz -C /tmp/ && mv /tmp/docker/docker /usr/bin/docker

# Customize here your container...


Then in order to connect to the docker outside your container you have to remember to create your container by:
docker run -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock <YOUR_IMAGE>

At this link https://devopscube.com/run-docker-in-docker/ you can find some more useful explanations.

I doubt that this is what the OP is asking about. They appear to want to be able to connect to the docker daemon on the host system.

I added further information about that.
